# Connections not showing on VSC with SQLTools

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code, sqltools

I don't know if this is the place to ask, but I'm desperate. So I've trying to make a connection with SQLTools on VSC, but it won't work. I think it is making the connection, but it's just not showing up. I don't know why this is, but I've tried re-installing both the extensions and MySQL itself. It also gives an error for an old database or connection that I thought had been deleted. I don't know how to delete a connection and how I am supposed to make a new one. Please help me. Thanks in advance[image: Here is a picture of the VSC screen and the error at the bottom right. I also don't know what the error is in the SQL console]

Comment: You can't use `MySQL` command on `Git` or any other VCS. You can use that command in `MySQL Workbench`.

Comment: Yeah but it's more about the fact that my connections don't show up and idk what the error in the bottom right is (might have something to do with it)

Comment: `Structured Query Language` is a query language to `read`, `write`, `update`, and
 `delete` data in the database. if you want to see if you have established a connection to your database through your `server`, first you need to create a server in one of the programming languages.

Comment: @polelord did you resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just press Ctrl + shift + p and search for SQLToolsManagement: Delete connection
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aqSO.png
2. Delete all the previous connections
3. Now add new connection

This worked for me.